# How do I load user controls in mobile web parts?

Tags: web-part, mobile

I want to load a user control like in a regular web part but in a mobile web part.

The regular method of doing it:

```
private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/WP7.SP.MobileWebPart/MobileWebPart/MobileWebPartUserControl.ascx";

protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
    Controls.Add(control);
}
```

How do I do it in a mobile web part?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! A well written question encourages people to answer it. Please read [our guidelines](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115/have-any-tips-for-editing-questions/116#116) which I've used to improve your post. You can also read [How to Ask](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with mobile development myself, but recently some mobile labs were released: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePointAndWindowsPhone7TrainingCourse_CreatingMobileWebPartsLab . It looks like that you already took some code from that lab, but I would suggest you to follow the lab completely: you will learn about mobile adapters, then.